# Sum of roots (number theory)

Tags: number-theory, natural-numbers

Let $k,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_k>0$ and $b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_m>0$

Let $\sqrt[n]{a_1} + \sqrt[n]{a_2} + \cdots + \sqrt[n]{a_k} = \sqrt[n]{b_1} + \sqrt[n]{b_2} + \cdots + \sqrt[n]{b_m}$ for all natural $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

1. Prove that $k = m$.
2. Prove that $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_k>0$ and $b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_k>0$
3. Prove that if each of the two sets of numbers sort of growth, then these sets will be the same.

Comment: This isn't quite right, as $\sqrt{8}=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Did you forget $\forall{i,j}:a_i,b_j\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_k$ and $b_1<b_2<\dots<b_m$?

Comment: @barakmanos This doesn't suffice either: $\sqrt 1+\sqrt 4 =\sqrt{9}$

Comment: barak manos, ∀i,j:ai,bj are not always natural and they are  sorted of growth

Comment: @JohnStark, both Aaron and Barak already provided with two rather clear counter examples to what you try to prove. Either change/add conditions or the claim simply isn't true.

Comment: @Timbuc, this equality is for all natural n, (n>1)

Comment: For question 1 in the updated version, consider the limits for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: OK, I've figured that adding a few restrictions would make your statement true, but as shown by @Hagen von Eitzen, those conditions are not sufficient either... You must be missing some other restriction then...

Comment: @barak manos, imagine that there are numbers, that make this equality exist

Comment: I don't know if it will be a sufficient condition, but a way to avoid both the counterexamples given above is to require that none of the $a_i,b_i$ are divisible by any $n$th powers of integers (other than $1^n$).